# Rails 3.2.12/HTML 5 offline manifest

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Where am I wrong ? I should have missed some important trick....
after compiling assets, and running my app in dev mode , going to root url

..**.I just get a white page ....
Is it because I am running in dev mode on localhost ?

the console :

```
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
  Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-12 19:09:46 +0100
  Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
  .....  more ...
  Rendered welcome/index.html.haml within layouts/application (438.3ms)
  Completed 200 OK in 3700ms (Views: 539.7ms | ActiveRecord: 101.8ms)
  Started GET "/fr/application.manifest" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-12 19:09:51 +0100
  CACHE MANIFEST
  # b674b99ed2e29478bf9b8887fd1448dcd5755e2b2f8882a9abf2030d70ae5ae5
  404.html
  422.html
  500.html
  offline.html
  assets/application-cb5548d93b80852ceb169309f728eb75.js 
  .... more assets ....
```

In my application.html.haml

```
 %html{:lang => "en", :manifest => manifest_path }
```

In my routes.rb

```
  Rack::Offline.configure do
    cache "assets/application.js"
    cache "assets/application.css"   
    network "/"
  end
  match "/application.manifest" => Rails::Offline, :as => :manifest
```

In my mimes_types.rb

```
Mime::Type.register "text/cache-manifest", :manifest
```